# Flutter: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe on android backpress

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have several pages in my app. Navigation is done as follows.

```
        Navigator.push(
         context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => ContactsPage(
              username: _username),
        ));
```

Then when I press the back button on android I see the following warning.

```
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for FocusManager:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
```

How do I get rid of this warning? The pages are not dialogs, they are stateful widgets.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @FrancisCajalne  I also have same problem. Did you guys get a solution for this. I got this issue when i press back button.